# How to emulate GATT server in Bluetooth Developer Studio while connected with a Physical Device?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

When a physical device is connected with Bluetooth Developer Studio (BDS), BDS treats it as GATT server and itself behaves like a client. But what if I want to check the client role on physical device.

I'm trying HID over GATT (HOGP) and my physical device works as HID Host role. I wanted to emulate BDS as HID Device but I didn't find any way to make it as HID Device while connected to a physical device as HID Host.

Is there any way or any plugin need to install to host services on BDS when it is connected to a phycial device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same functionality in BDS, but after looking into it I found that it only supports interfacing with a physical peripheral device and not central devices. I follow the Bluetooth SIG webinars and updates on the roadmap for the tool as well, and this functionality is not listed in their future roadmap for releases.

BDS plugins are only supported for source code generation (at least up to version 1.1).